# Responding to links under an overlay div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**The scenario is this.**

I've built a top navigation prototype which needs to have an overlay (transparent PNG) image on top of it. It currently covers about 1/3 of the links. **Please see below:**

[image]

Is there any way I can make the top 1/3 of the links respond even-though there's a `<div />` covering them partly? The overlay won't contain anything clickable it's only a design feature.

I've never done this and wouldn't imagine it's possible but I look forward to being proven wrong.

`Javascript/jQuery` not preferred but will use as a last resort.

**Here's a [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pXXpU/5/)**, it directly mimics the structure of my current code.

Comment: You should be able to do it with some combination of `position: relative`, `position: absolute`, `z-index`, and possibly having to change the order of some elements in your HTML. It's difficult to give specifics without a live link or a test case. What's the point of the transparent PNG overlay?

Comment: @thirtydot, I've added a jsFiddle with a test case.

Comment: @Marko: Anything wrong [with this](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pXXpU/6/)?

Comment: @thirtydot, the image needs to cover the links, not the other way around.

Comment: @Marko: Ah, I see the problem.

Comment: It looks like I'll have to move the menu down thus making the links appear below the overlay.. Unless you have other ideas :/

Comment: @Marko: I posted the only answer I can think of. It's fairly annoying to do in practise, but it should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this **IS POSSIBLE** using ***pointer-events: none***!

**CSS**

```
div.overlay {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Compatibility for IE (http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) is still non-existent so a conditional CSS statement is required:

```
    <!--[if IE]>
        <style type="text/css">
            .overlay {
                background: none !important;
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

If using an overlay div with CSS gradient background the above is enough. If using a transparent image (png, gif, etc), you'll need to add this to your conditional statement:

```
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='file-name.png', sizingMethod='scale');
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

you could make a transparent image the size of the tab and then put that image as a link and position it perfectly over the tab.

Comment: I don't quite follow you, explain further perhaps? Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 1):

There's only one way to do this (as far as I know), and it's not great:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pXXpU/7/)

- Add the same background image (to each) button that your `.png` with alpha channel overlaps.
- Use `background-position` with pixel perfect offsets.

I'm lucky that in that demo it only overlapped the last button :)

Comment: Yeah I thought of that too but guess what. The menu items are 100% dynamic :)

Comment: @Marko: Thought I'd solved it there, ah well. What does `100% dynamic` mean? `%` based width?

Comment: The menu accross the site is dynamic, meaning they're not fixed width but rather are shrinkwrapped and calculated using their font-size + padding.

Comment: @Marko: Can't think of anything else :( (without resorting to jQuery to figure out the `background-position` based on button width)

Answer (score 0):

No, only the top layer is clickable.

Comment: This is my opinion too, care to see if it's definitely the case!

Answer (score 0):

the click() event can be emulated via jquery, although it may not apply to your problem...

You could also (as a last resort) replace the navigation and place it on top more or less like an imagemap...

Comment: The navigation is dynamic, that won't really work. Imagemap is also obsolete.

Comment: or maybe place the text part of the navigation to the top?, anyway, clicking on any part covered by the top div/image won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... use links with no text, with display: block and width and height set. Put inside a DIV as container and z-index to be over the divs from the menu, and position: absolute. Then set the right position for the container. Something like:

```
.linkOverlay
{
   z-index: 10;
   display: block;
   width: 100px;
   height: 40px;
   float: left;
}
.linkContainer{
   position: absolute;
   top: (top here);
   left: (left here);
}
[div class="linkContainer"]
    [a href="page.html" class="linkOverlay"][/a]
    [a href="page_two.html" class="linkOverlay"][/a]
[/div]
```

That's just the main idea, you will know how to do it :)

Comment: @Michael, see my update and comments above. The image needs to be on TOP of the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this works in all but ie7, and is almost all CSS.  It just requires adding a little html:

http://jsfiddle.net/pXXpU/8/