# Transparent div overlaping Google's logo on Google maps

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On my website's homepage there's a big picture which take 100% of the width and 60% of the height (it's a div with a css background-picture not an  tag).
Over this picture, there's is a black transparent div (mainFormContainer) with some form input.
Two of those inputs are address field which are bind to Google Place autocomplete.

Here is the HTML code

```
<div id="titleContainer" class="splash-container" style="position: relative;" >
    <div id="mapContainer" style="width: 100%; position: absolute;top: 0;"></div>
    <div  id="mainFormContainer" class="splash-bottom">
        <form></form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically what I did is that when an address is filled by clicking on an autocomplete suggestion (event place_changed in javascript) I initialize & display the google map with a marker on the location.

It works fine and looks great but the problem is that the mainFormContainer is over the Google logo of the google Maps (bottom left corner) and over the map's data (bottom right corner).
Since the div is transparent `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);` the bottom data is not hidden and I used this solution ([Responding to links under an overlay div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253289/responding-to-links-under-an-overlay-div)) to make the below link clickable.

However, because my div is not transparent, this data is less visible and I'm not sure if it'll be a problem.
I would like to know if there is a solution to add some padding to the google logo & the bottom right data of the map ?

I've seen that you can do it on ios (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map#map_padding) but I didn't found anything equivalent for the javascript API

---

The only solution I could find was to add some invisible div as map controls to add padding but it doesn't work on the bottom data.

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(createDummyDiv('100%', '20%'));
```

But since it add a div in the google maps, I tried the following code :

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER].push(cloneSearchBar());
function cloneSearchBar()
{
    var clone = $('#mainFormContainer').clone(true);
    clone.css('width', '100%');
    clone.css('height', $('#mainFormContainer').height());
    console.log(clone[0]);
    return clone[0];
}
```

This trick gave me numerous new problem :

1. The Google Place autocomplete doesn't work (Autocomplete suggestion doesn't show at all)
2. The design for the font are herited from the maps and not my CSS
3. I have a field input with a datepicker that doesn't work as expected. The datepicker appear but when I click on a date, it doesn't fill the input.

So I gave up on this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These elements have a common property, they are placed via CSS at: `bottom: 0px;`

You may use this to create a selector:

```
#mapContainer div[style*="bottom: 0px"]
```

to apply the padding you may use a transparent border at the bottom:

```
  #mapContainer div[style*="bottom: 0px"]{
    border-bottom:50px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/m2rumozm/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/m2rumozm/)

But I'm not sure if it's a good approach(the API may change), you better try your final attempt(use the form as map-control). The issues #1 + #3 probably may be fixed when you add the original `#mainFormContainer` instead of a clone(at least an autocomplete works without problems as a control, I've added an autocomplete to the fiddle to demonstrate it). Issue  #2 should be solvable via  CSS.

Comment: And I am not sure this would not be against the TOS. You are not supposed to *delete, obscure, or in any manner alter any brand features, logos [...]* - Would this be considered as *altering*?

Comment: It works perfectly !! Very clever solution I must say ! Regarding the TOS, I don't know either, but what I'm trying to do here is to respect them. A div overlapping the bottom of the map is clearly obscuring the brand features.

Comment: @MrUpsidown they only want google logo appear on the maps, its ok to move the logo upper or lower without making the logo obscure

Comment: @SnowBases reference?

Comment: @MrUpsidown https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide/